# Why wordpress cookies name contains HASH

Tags: cookies

As documented [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/cookies/), wordpress cookies name have HASH part. I wonder to know what is its use-case?

Comment: It's there in [the docs you linked](https://wordpress.org/support/article/cookies/#non-version-specific-data): "It’s quite hard to reverse a hash (bordering on practical infeasibility with today’s computers). [...] WordPress uses the two cookies to bypass the password entry portion of `wp-login.php`."

Comment: I know why cookie data is hashed, my question is bout cookie's name.

Answer (score 1):

Hash is used to encrypt the data saved in cookies, So, you don’t have to worry about someone getting your username and password by reading the cookie data.